# Adding a onclick dynamically using an Html Helper in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need the ability to dynamically set an onclick using an HTML Helper.  the below is what I'm trying to do, but i'm getting an obvious syntax error

```
<%=Html.CheckBox("checkboxname", item.Id = 3, New With {.onclick = "ajaxThis(this, <%= Html.Encode(item.ID) %>, '<%= Html.Encode(item.NUMBER) %>');"})%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to remove the <%= %> from <%= Html.Encode(item.ID) %> and just call Html.Encode(item.ID) directly.  Do the same with the item.NUMBER encoding.

Something like:

```
"ajaxThis(this, " + Html.Encode(item.ID) + ", '" + Html.Encode(item.NUMBER) + "');"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're entering a string, so just concat the string instead:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("checkboxname", item.Id = 3, New With {.onclick = String.Concat("ajaxThis(this, ", Html.Encode(item.ID), ", '", Html.Encode(item.NUMBER), "');")})%>
```

However, it would probably be easier to just add a css class and hook up an event handler using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/).