# How to trigger an ajax event with a checkbox click in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I searched the database, and I found someone talking about it but not demonstrating the fact
[Adding a onclick dynamically using an Html Helper in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899669/adding-a-onclick-dynamically-using-an-html-helper-in-mvc)

I would like to trigger ajax on a check box onclick event

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.HasChildren, new { onclick = "return Triger2();" })
```

Can I execute an AJAX trigger, or can someone please direct me to the jQuery method where I would catch the click event. Then how would it execute the AJAX trigger?

```
          <div id="Stream1"> @Ajax.ActionLink("Click", "Triger2", new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "Stream1",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "Get",
                LoadingElementId = "progress"
            })
         </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

well you can do this

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.HasChildren)
```

later on have below to capture click of checkbox and call ajax.

```
$("#HasChildren").click(function(){
 $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("actionmethod", "controllername")',
            type: "POST",
            data: //data,
            dataType: //type of response,
            success: function (data) {
//ur code here
}
error: function(data){

}
});});
```

}

**NOTE :** if you wanna call ajax not on click but only if value is checked or not then you must use an **if** condition in the click event to check the same using `$(this).is(:checked)`

Comment: Better use $("#HasChildren").change(function() to avoid additional checking.